# how can I ignore invalid ssl certificates in getting a webspage as an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, ssl

I have a printer (several actually) and I want to get their status pages and make a little dom parser tell me when supplies are low. No big deal, except the printers throw an invalid ssl certificate warning before loading. I can use wget to get the pages like this:

```
$wget -m --no-check-certificates 10.4.102.125
```

but I'd rather just use php if its not too convoluted to do it.

here is a basic example of how I'm downloading the pages as arrays:

```
<?php
$target = "http://10.4.102.125";
$downloaded_page_array = file($target);

for($i=0; $i<count($downloaded_page_array); $i++)
   echo $downloaded_page_array[$i];
?>
```

How can I ignore invalid ssl certificates in getting a webspage and just go to the page I want to get, as an array in php?

I do not want to change my server settings. Also, I have never figured out how to upgrade the ssl certificates on any of these printers successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use curl

And to skip invalid SSL warrning use following options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

for example

```
<?php 
        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://10.4.102.125"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using wrappers to retrieve the pages you need to set [context options and parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php). In this case, the options you are looking for belong to [SSL](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) (which also apply to HTTPS) and I believe you want to disable this:

> `verify_peer` boolean
>
> Require verification of SSL certificate used.

Once you set the context, you need to pass it as third argument to [file](http://php.net/file):

> ```
> array file ( string $filename [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )
> ```